# Django: Add multiple user to one group in admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin

At the moment i'm settting up the permissions in my project and i assigned some permissions to one user group. Now i have to assign a large number of users to this group, so that they can us the permissions of the group.

**Problem:**
I have to click on every user in the admin interface, add them to the group and the same for the next ones. This takes a large amount of time. Is it possible to select anywhere all users that should belong to a group? That would be much faster...

If it's not possible with the standard admin interface, is there an app I can install and use for this (like "South" for database migration tasks)?

Answer (score 5):

Use the django shell:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
>>> the_group = Group.objects.get(name='the_name_in_admin')
>>> users = User.objects.exclude(groups__name='the_group_you_made_in_admin')
>>> for i in users:
...    i.groups.add(the_group)
...    i.save()
>>>
```

For more information on the api of the authentication system, have a read through the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization)

Comment: Just for the clarity, you don't need to execute `obj.save()`, `m2m.add()` method  is saving the result to DB anyway.